# How to limit the number of strings (characters/words) in a column using DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to limit the number of character shown in the output of a DataFrame.

Here is an example of a DataFrame:

```
     Abc                       XYZ
0  Hello   How are you doing today
1   Good   This is a job well done
2    Bye          See you tomorrow
3  Books  Read chapter 1 to 5 only
```

Desired output:

```
     Abc                       XYZ
0  Hello                   How are 
1   Good                   This is
2    Bye                   See you
3  Books              Read chapter
```

This is what I tried:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_info_rows', 2)
pd.set_option('display.max_info_columns', 2)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 2)
```

`max_info_rows` and `max_info_columns` did not do anything, while `max_colwidth` actually expanded the characters further.

Anyway to limit the number of characters in a dataframe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.XYZ.apply(lambda x : x.rsplit(maxsplit=len(x.split())-2)[0])

0         How are
1         This is
2         See you
3    Read chapter
```

just reassign it back:

```
df.XYZ = df.XYZ.apply(lambda x : x.rsplit(maxsplit=len(x.split())-2)[0])
print(df)

     Abc           XYZ
0  Hello       How are
1   Good       This is
2    Bye       See you
3  Books  Read chapter
```

Comment: this works, but it ignores the first column, how do we show the first column as well?

Answer (score 1):

Getting Pandas to display only two words of each string will be tricky. Strings in Python don't really have a concept of separate "words", per se. What you could do is split each string up into a list of strings (one string per word), and then limit the number of list items that Pandas prints, using the `'display.max_seq_items'` option:

```
import pandas as pd

d = '''     Abc                       XYZ
0  Hello   "How are you doing today"
1   Good   "This is a job well done"
2    Bye          "See you tomorrow"
3  Books  "Read chapter 1 to 5 only"'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(d), sep='\s+')

# convert the XYZ values from str to list of str
df['XYZ'] = df['XYZ'].str.split()

# only display the first 2 values in each list of word strings
with pd.option_context('display.max_seq_items', 2):
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Abc                   XYZ
0  Hello       [How, are, ...]
1   Good       [This, is, ...]
2    Bye       [See, you, ...]
3  Books  [Read, chapter, ...]
```